# Complexity of searching an element in list Vs set

Tags: java, collections, complexity-theory

Consider, if I have to search for a particular row in a table, as per ORM each row is an object I believe. I did not work intensely on JDBC, so generally as a better practice where are these POJO objects collected or holded? In a set or list?

I am trying to find the complexity of searching an element in a List Vs. Set

What I have done?

```
private void searchSet() {
        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
        names.add("srk");
        names.add("lastminute");
        names.add("monkey");
        for(String x:names){
            if(x.equals("monkey")){
                System.out.println("caught the name "+x);
            }
        }

}



private void searchList() {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("srk");
    names.add("lastminute");
    names.add("monkey");
    for(String x:names){
        if(x.equals("monkey")){
            System.out.println("caught the name "+x);
        }
    }

}
```

I am calculating the time taken to search element in set and list using the following approach.

```
    long startTime,endTime,totalTime;
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    totalTime = endTime - startTime;
```

Now, I have the statistics which are hereunder

```
System.out.println("Time taken to search an element in list : "+totalTime);//for list - 614324 
System.out.println("Time taken to search an element in set : "+totalTime);//for set - 757359
```

Based on these stats can conclude that its faster to search an element in List than set?
Which is a better collection to store database record objects, for searching. What is the complexity of searching an element in a List Vs Set. in a generic sense?

Answer (score 7):

Data structures don't have complexities, algorithms have. (Note that data structures usually come with the complexities of their basic operations, which are tiny algorithms themselves.) In your case, you implemented the find algorithm yourself for both containers, and you did it as a linear search, which is O(n). The speed difference you observed is the result of an ArrayList being simpler and faster to traverse than a HashSet, i.e. the algorithm has the same complexity, but the constant factor is smaller.

Second, you have I/O within the functions you want to time. This will usually completely dominate any actual operations you perform and make your benchmark useless.

Third, you're looking for complexity and you wrote a benchmark. That's just wrong. You can get a hint for complexity by having a benchmark and plotting the results for different input sizes in a graph, but to really learn the complexity, you have to analyze the algorithm, not run it.

Fourth, List and Set in Java aren't data structures, they are interfaces. The data structures you have chosen are ArrayList (a version of the contiguous array data structure implementing the List interface) and HashSet (a version of the hash table data structure implementing the Set interface). So you need to look at those.

For an array, unless it's sorted, the find algorithm takes linear time, because you have no option other than traversing the whole thing.

For a hash table, which is optimized for lookup, the find algorithm is still technically O(n) in the worst case, but in the common case will be O(1). However, you have to actually use the optimized find algorithm (offered by Set.contains) in order to exploit this - a linear search over HashSet is no better (and actually worse) than a linear search over an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

There are already method `contain()` given in both the collections then why are you again traversing ? complexity for list is `O(n)` and for set it is `O(1)` which is constant.

Comment: I think that the complexity is O(1) for a map only because you can find the value with its key. In a set, there is no reason you can find the element at once.

Comment: A list and Set should have O(n/2). Worst case O(n), best case O(1).

Comment: you are right but I am talking about best case when all element lie in different buckets . Worst complexity could be O(n) however I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

List Implementation code:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/List.cs,eabc7101897ec6e6

Set Implementation Code:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,50c894a3f7ad7bd0

Data Structure Time Complexity:
https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

Useful book: Introduction to the design and analysis of algorithms by Anany Levitin

The first two links demonstrate the inner implementation for the Set class and the List, basically both of them are implemented using the Array data structure type.
The third link demonstrate each data structure complexity for different operations.
If you wish to measure the complexity for the two different code (Set, List) we could

1. Use Time complexity for algorithm analysis by looking at the most operation compensating for the most of time the algorithm takes to solve a problem.
   2.Set up a sum expressing the number of times the algorithm’s basic operation
   is executed
2. Using standard formulas and rules of sum manipulation, either find a closed-
   form formula for the count or, at the very least, establish its order of growth.